# Command line move files/folders up in the directory tree

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a folder containing a bunch of subfolders and files, but the structure is a bit inefficient.  For example:

Root Folder
----EmptyFolder1
--------Folder1
------------SubFolder1
------------File1
------------File2
----EmptyFolder2
--------Folder2
------------SubFolder2
------------File3
------------File4

How can I move all of the Folders/SubFolders/Files up in the tree and eliminate all of the EmptyFolders so that it looks more like this:

Root Folder
----Folder1
--------SubFolder1
--------File1
--------File2
----Folder2
--------SubFolder2
--------File3
--------File4

Comment: If they all follow `EmptyFolderX` with the subfolders `Folder1`, you can't, because you can only have a single folder named `Folder1` in a directory, and moving all of them up one level would result in multiples. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @KenWhite, The ones labeled as "Folder1" do indeed have unique names.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and indicate that fact. As written, the question isn't clear on that aspect. (I'm not sure why you'd need a batch file to do this, BTW; it should be a one-time operation, and unless you have thousands of "EmptyFolderX" items, it would seem to be very quick to just drag/drop in Windows Explorer to get this done.)

Comment: @KenWhite, I have about 7,000 directories that need to be moved this way.  That's why I'm looking for an automated way to do it.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Are all of the empty folders actually named "thesametext" followed by an incrementing number (like "EmptyFolder1", "EmptyFolder2" or "DummyFolder1", "DummyFolder2"), or is the "empty folder" different every time?

Comment: @KenWhite, unfortunately no.  They are all fairly random strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t h r e e"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir/s/b/a-d "%sourcedir%"'
 ) DO (
 CALL :movefile %%a
)

:loop
SET "zapped="
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (.) DO (
 RD "%%a" >NUL 2>NUL
 IF NOT EXIST "%%a" SET zapped=Y
)
IF DEFINED zapped GOTO loop
DIR /s/b/ad "%sourcedir%

GOTO :EOF

:movefile
SET "oldfn=%*"
SET "newfn=!oldfn:%sourcedir%\=!"
SET "newfn=%sourcedir%\%newfn:*\=%"
FOR %%r IN ("%newfn%") DO (
 ECHO MD "%%~dpr"
 ECHO MOVE "%oldfn%" "%newfn%"
)

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

**caution** test on a representative subtree first!

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The section after the `:loop` label deletes any empty directories in the subtree. Of necessity, the commands are **executed** not merely displayed.

Be very, very careful about file/directorynames that contain symbols with special meaning to `cmd`.